# Relationship between Green's function and impulse response

Tags: differential-equations, dirac-delta-distributions, greens-functions, linear-systems

In my field, electrical engineering, we frequently study linear time-invariant systems of the following form:

$$
a_n\frac{d^ny}{dt^n} + a_{n-1}\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dt^{n-1}} + \ldots + a_1\frac{dy}{dt} + a_0y(t) = b_m\frac{d^nx}{dt^n} + b_{m-1}\frac{d^{n-1}x}{dt^{n-1}} + \ldots + b_1\frac{dx}{dt} + b_0x(t),
$$
or, using operator notation,
$$
Ly = Rx,
$$
where $x(t)$ is some input function (signal), and $y(t)$ is the system response. Using the Laplace transform, one can find the solution $y(t)$ for a generic input $x(t)$, assuming the system is relaxed, using the convolution integral:
$$
y(t) = \int h(\tau) x(t-\tau) d\tau,
$$
where $h(t)$ is the response of the system to a unit impulse, $\delta(t)$. This formulation is ubiquitous in engineering literature. The reason we don't simply just compute the derivatives on the RHS is that we want to study the behavior of the system independent of what input is being applied.

However, in physics and applied mathematics literature, I usually see the following form:
$$
Ly = x,
$$
for which the solution is found using the Green's function:
$$
y(t) = \int G(\tau) x(t-\tau) d\tau,
$$
which appears to be a special case when $R = I$.

How do physicists deal with the case when $R \ne I$?

Another related question: Is is possible to rewrite any linear, constant coefficient differential equation:
$$
Ly = Rx
$$
in this form?:
$$
R^{-1}Ly = x.
$$
If so, that could alleviate this concern.

Comment: Final comment in question seems accurate to me, though it is no longer a differential equation, then, but an [integro-differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integro-differential_equation).

Comment: I think I'm saying the same thing, but what is wrong with inserting *Rx* after the Green's function *G* in the integral?

Comment: Isn't the $L \ y = x$ form just a linear response while the $L \ y = R \ x$ form is a nonlinear response?

Comment: @honeste_vivere, it's not a nonlinear response since both $L$ and $R$ are differential operators, e.g., $$R = \sum_n r_n \frac{d^n}{dt^n}$$  Taking the Laplace transform of both sides gives the transfer function:  $$H(s) \equiv \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{R(s)}{L(s)}$$ i.e., the poles come from the $L$ operator while the zeros come from the $R$ operator.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - Ah okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Green's functions are more general since time (or shift) invariance isn't required.  For example, a time *varying* system has a Green's function $G(t,\tau)$ where, in general, $G(t - \tau, 0) \ne G(t,\tau)$, i.e., the response to $\delta(t - \tau)$ is not the time shifted response to $\delta(t)$.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri You are correct that shift invariance is not required for Green's functions; it is not required for impulse responses either, but I chose shift-invariant systems to simplify the issue.

Comment: Carlos, for a system to have *an* impulse response, $h(t)$, it must be LTI.  If it's not time invariant, 'the' impulse response is $h(t,\tau)$ which is actually a parametrized family of functions that are not related by a shift.  Regardless, it's clear that you're looking for something else besides what I brought up.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The notation you mentioned, $h(t,\tau)$, is precisely what is called an impulse response when the system is time-varying. This terminology is standard in the literature: e.g. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1088793/, also A. Goldsmith, "Wireless Communications", 2005

Comment: Carlos, I'm fully aware of this fact (though through other literature, e.g., [this](http://control.ucsd.edu/mauricio/courses/mae280a/lecture8.pdf). But I'm also aware of the phrase *time varying impulse response* that is used in the literature.